# Treasure chests probability

Tags: probability

My roommates and I were looking at dutch redband treasure chest candies [link for the candy](https://hollandshopper.nl/red-band-schatkistjes). One pack contains 14 chests with candy as treasure inside. On the face of every chest is 1/12th of a treasure map displayed. in other words, when you have 12 distinct pieces of the map, you have completed the "puzzle". We were wondering, what is the probability that you receive a full map in one pack?

We assume that:

1. the supplier does fill the packs randomly and
2. the supplier has an infinite supply of every map piece

So as a more general problem:
We have a 12 sided dice, which is thrown 14 times. What is the probability that we get each face of the dice at least once.

Comment: We wrote a python script which approximately 0.12551%

Comment: See the [coupon-collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  See also [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  The probability you ask about is $\dfrac{{14\brace 12}12!}{12^{14}}\approx 0.00125615$ [wolfram calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StirlingS2%5B14%2C12%5D*12%21%2F12%5E14)